# Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 WiFi slow speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ipv6, manjaro

I already asked [this in the Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/qualcomm-atheros-ar9462-wifi-slow-speed/83841) but I thought maybe somebody here could also help me.

I recently changed my internet provider. They changed the router and the WiFi network. Before that my WiFi connection speed worked fined but now I only have 0 - 1Mb speed. In my phone I have 100Mb.

I’ve tried ***adding ipv6 disable & pcie_aspm=off via grub boot parameters*** following [this solution](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-atheros-qca9377-wifi-speed-very-slow/129019/7) but it only worked ONCE. When I turned off and on my laptop it had the problem again and the solution didn’t work.

This is the inxi -Nazy result:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 02:00.0 
  chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: AzureWave 
  driver: ath9k v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 168c:0034 
  class-ID: 0280
```

And this is my system info:

```
Operating System: Manjaro Linux
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.85.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.14.2-1-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 7,7 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear: you had no problems with the internet speeds with old ISP? you're absolutely sure you changed nothing in the system settings when you changed to new ISP?

Comment: Nope, I didn't change anything. System settings are the same. I tried with an ethernet cable and the connection works fine: 200Mb. When I connect via WiFi: 0.37 - 0.8Mb.

Comment: The linked solution suggests disabling IPv6. Is it now enabled? If yes, please do disable it and test again. It doesn't sound to me like the problems' on your system per se. It basically has to be the router, or the communication between the two.

Comment: I just disabled it: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet apparmor=1 security=apparmor udev.log_priority=3 ipv6.disable=1 pcie_aspm=off net.ifnames=0". Also, the technician rebooted the connection and the configuration in the router. but still not working :(

Comment: Just cheking - you did make the change by editing `/etc/default/grub` and command `sudo update-grub`, right? And you did reboot after that? If not, please do, then test.

Comment: Yes, I did it like that.